# How can I set the shortcut for "Redo" from Ctrl+Shift+Z to Ctrl+Y?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

I use Ubuntu 16.04, and would like to change the shortcut for Redoing a certain action (i.e., to counteract the previously used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, as it is standard in Windows and therefore in my subconscious typing.

I followed [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html) instructions but could not find how to specifically change this shortcut, as I could not find it in the Keyboard settings.

Comment: Isn't the link you have provided for 18.04 LTS?

Comment: This is application-specific or at least toolkit-specific (GTK+ vs. Qt, etc.) and not related to system- or session-wide shortcuts as [described in your link](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html). In what application(s) do you want to change the shortcut?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, actually it was Spyder, but I did manage to change it from its settings. System-wise though I have not been able to, yet.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I know, I do that a lot actually. Here although my first issue started in Spyder, and was solved in Spyder, my question is about Ubuntu 16.04's default keywords at system level. I still don't know how to do it. In fact, I don't even mention Spyder in my question.

Comment: _“to Ctrl+Y, as it is standard in Windows”_ This simply isn’t true. I have been struggling with the same problem on Windows, too. It depends on each application…

Comment: @Melebius, I can't think of any Microsoft owned application where CTRL+Y is not applying Redo. Perhaps third-party applications may set it differently, but Windows' standard remains Redo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you explicitly ask for a system- or at lease session-wide solution in the comments: this cannot be done in a way that doesn't break lots of other things.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcuts that you mention are handled on the application level. Although it's possible to intercept and “translate” them before they ever reach an application it would interfere with many other things, e. g. applications that bind these to unrelated actions.<sup>1</sup>

Instead I recommend that you change the on the application level. Many applications without a distinct interface to change keyboard shortcuts still allow changes to them through their toolkit configuration, e. g.

- [GTK+ applications](//wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK+#Keyboard_shortcuts) and
- [KDE applications](//docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/khotkeys/shortcuts.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> If you still want to try it please look at `xmodmap` or `xdotool`. Relevant questions are:

- [Make shortcut for navigational functions](/q/27295/175814)
- [Create custom keyboard shortcut to send Super+2](/q/538017/175814)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind actually explicate how to modify the basic bindings of the system? The warning will not be forgotten, but I'd like to know it!

Comment: @raggot: See the update to my answer.